# Navigating from fourth view to second view without allocating memory to the view?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am struck in an issue were I have to navigate from fourth view to second view, now i want to know how to navigate without allocating memory to second view in fourth view. I know how to navigate from any view to root view using `popToRootViewController:` but I couldn't figure out this issue.

I hope some will help me in clearing this issue,Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[[self navigationController] popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];`

You should change the `objectAtIndex` accordingly, in my example it goes to the 2nd view.

Comment: So you are saying that when view is navigating from one to another the navigation controller will store the views in stack, so I need to see the stack `ObjectAtIndex` were the second view object is stored.

Comment: @SantoshGurram, yup AFAIK. I usually use nav controller from the first view. So it stores the first view at index 0 and so forth.